# Draw on image using actual pixel

Tags: android, image-processing, canvas

My aim is to draw on top of a resource image.

So, I load the image from my resources:

```
bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
```

I know this is not the best way since it can couse memory problems, but it's not my concern now...
Then, I create a canvas and draw on it

```
Canvas canv = new Canvas(bm);
canv.drawLine(0, 10, 50, 70, paint);
```

Then I export the Bitmap to a file.

Now, the problems are:

- The coordinates I use to draw the line are not pixels of the original image
- If I run the app in different devices, with different screens, the resulting image is different (the line has different position and size)

Is there a way to specify the coordinates w.r.t. the pixels of the original image, or a way to get the image result the same in different devices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you'd faced is because of Android Density conception. It means that when you create a bitmap from R.drawable.id, it scales the image according to device density.
The mechanism is nearly as follows:

1. Check device density and select the most suitable drawable for this id: from drawable-hdpi/mdpi/.../default. That will result that on each device you'll have different sized, if you'd put the image to different folders(hdpi, mdpi, etc)
2. If there is no well-suitable drawable(for example you'd provided only one in /drawable/ folder, but none in /drawable-hpi(etc)/) - it uses this default drawable, but scales it, based on device density and "default denisity".

You can check details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

However, if you just need the same bitmap resolution on all devices, I can suggest 2 approaches:

1) Place your image not into drawable/ folder, but just into one: /drawable-**nodpi**. It will prevent it from scaling and will deny Android to adjust it for device density

2) You can try this approach:

```
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
```

In that way you can avoid Android density-scaling system and get the bitmap exactly of the size of the resource in /drawable/ folder.

Please let me know if some more details are needed. Good luck

Comment: Would you recommend any of the two approaches?

Comment: Glad to help :)
Actually both are good, I think. But if you'll use 2nd - be sure you'd placed the file to default 'drawable' folder. Because if you'll place it to 'drawables-mdpi'(for example) - the code can crash on hdpi/xhdpi devices, as android does not supports 'upscaling' and can say "no resource".

Answer (score 0):

I believe this could be because you are putting the Bitmap into the `res/drawable` folder. Depending on the device you run your app, the resolution will change of the bitmap, hence the line not being drawn as wanted.

You can fix this by placing the bitmap in the assets folder and loading it as following:

```
public Bitmap readBitmapFromMemory(String filename) {
        Bitmap defautBitmap = null;
        File filePath = this.getFileStreamPath(filename);
        FileInputStream fi;
        try {
            fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            defautBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);

        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return defautBitmap;

    }
```

I hope this helps.